# Tensorflow compute_weighted_loss Example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use Tensorflows tf.losses.compute_weighted_loss but cannot find any good example. I have a multi-class classification problem and use the tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits as loss. Now I want to weigh the errors for each label independently. Let's say I have n labels, that means I need a n-sized weight vector. Unfortunately tf expects me to pass a (b, n) shaped matrix of error weights, where b is the batch size. So basically I would need to repeat the weight vector b times. That's okay given a fixed batch size, but if my batch size is variable (e.g. smaller batch at the end of the dataset) I have to adapt. Is there a way around this or did I miss something?

Comment: Nevermind. I just had to reshape the vector from (n,) to (1,n) to make the broadcasting possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to reshape the vector from (n,) to (1,n) to make the broadcasting possible:

```
error_weights = error_weights.reshape(1, error_weights.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the existing answer, use [tf.expand_dims](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) if `error_weights` is a `Tensor`.

```
error_weights = tf.expand_dims(error_weights, 0)  # changes shape [n] to [1, n]
```